# How to optimize? HackerRank: Time limit exceeded Allowed time limit:10 secs Your code did not execute in time. When trying python

Tags: python, optimization

How can I optmize this interactions? I'm getting timeout on just a few test cases on HackerRank

```
import math
#
# Complete the 'nearlySimilarRectangles' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return a LONG_INTEGER.
# The function accepts 2D_LONG_INTEGER_ARRAY sides as parameter.
#
def nearlySimilarRectangles(sides):
    # Write your code here
    leng = len(sides)
    i = 0
    rectan = 0
    #print('Sides ' + str(sides))
    if len(sides)>10**5:
        return
    while len(sides)>0:
        i = sides[0]
        sides.remove(i)
        #print('Sides Inter ' + str(sides))
        for z in sides:
            if i[0]/z[0] == i[1]/z[1]:
                rectan = rectan +1
            print(str(i[0]) +' ' +str(z[0])+ ' '+ str(i[1]) +' ' +str(z[1]))
    print('Sum ' + str(rectan))
    return(rectan)
```

And:

```
def mostActive(customers):
    # Write your code here
    unique=[]
    cont = []
    n = len(customers)
    for i in customers:
        if i not in unique:
            unique.append(i)
            cont.append([i,1])
        else:
            sd = unique.index(i)
            cont[sd][1]=cont[sd][1]+1
    
    unique.sort()
    for i in cont:
        if i[1]/n < 0.05:
            unique.remove(i[0])
    return(unique)
```

Tried HackerRank test, passed 10/15, the rest were triggered due to:

Time limit exceeded
Allowed time limit:10 secs
Your code did not execute in time. Please optimize your code. For more details on runtime environment, click the “Info” button